# Sorting the PDF Invoice by A Custom Attribute.

Tags: magento-1.6

I have created an attribute called stocknumber which assists me in finding products on the shelf. I need to have my PDF invoice ordered by this attribute. I currently have it sorting by 'name' and this works but I think I need to add my new attribute to the 'order_invoice_item_collection', Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
require_once 'Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php';

class Signalfly_SortingInvoices_Model_Order_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
{
    public function getItemsCollection()
    {
        if (empty($this->_items)) {

            $this->_items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_item_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setInvoiceFilter($this->getId())->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');

            if ($this->getId()) {
                foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
                    $item->setInvoice($this);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order item and subsequently the invoice item are detached from the product which has the attribute 'stocknumber'. Two approaches you could take:

1. Load the associated product from the invoice item, it has access to
   the product_id. This can become an issue if your product changes
   after the order has been placed/gets deleted.
2. Carry over your stocknumber in a custom column on order item and invoice item. The issue here would be if you change a stocknumber since it would not update the stocknumber for already placed orders.

--EDIT--

Since you are only interested in the Invoice PDF I would suggest to only change Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice

Based on Vinai's excellent answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277816/magento-get-collection-of-order-items-for-a-product-collection-filtered-by-an-a
the below gives you the invoice items sorted by an attribute. Change $attributeCode to your own one.

It replaces the call to $invoice->getAllItems() to a specially crafted collection.

```
/**
 * Return PDF document
 *
 * @param  array $invoices
 * @return Zend_Pdf
 */
public function getPdf($invoices = array())
{
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page  = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
            $order,
            Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId())
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber(
            $page,
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
        );
        /* Add table */
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */

        $attributeCode = 'test_sorting';
        $alias = $attributeCode.'_table';
        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_item_collection')
                        ->setInvoiceFilter($invoice->getId());

        $select = $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array($alias => $attribute->getBackendTable()),
            "main_table.product_id = $alias.entity_id AND $alias.attribute_id={$attribute->getId()}",
            array($attributeCode => 'value')
        )->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('ABS('.$attributeCode.')'));

        foreach ($collection as $item){
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem() || $item->isDeleted()) {
                continue;
            }
            $item->setInvoice($invoice);
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
        }
    }
    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}
```

The above code will likely make the attribute a required value or else the item might not show.

Comment: Thanks, so let's assume direction 1 was ok, how could I go about loading the product info into the invoice item before the invoice is sorted? What would that join look like? I am fairly new to Magento's methods.